# Django HttpResponse: Download Excel After User Clicks a Button

Tags: django, python-3.x

In my Django project, I need to send an in-memory Excel file to the client side for download. The download should start after the user clicks a button.

I've this code in `app/views.py` so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO as IO
from django.http import HttpResponse
import xlsxwriter


def write_to_excel():

    df_output = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['abc', 'def'], 'col2': ['ghi', 'jkl']})

    # my "Excel" file, which is an in-memory output file (buffer) 
    # for the new workbook
    excel_file = IO()

    xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter')

    df_output.to_excel(xlwriter, 'sheetname')

    xlwriter.save()
    xlwriter.close()

    # rewind the buffer
    excel_file.seek(0)

    # set the mime type so that the browser knows what to do with the file
    response = HttpResponse(excel_file.read(), content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')

    # set the file name in the Content-Disposition header
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=myfile.xlsx'

    return response
```

Here's my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
    <title>Generate Data</title>    
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <!-- {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }} -->
        <input type="submit" value="Excel">
    </form>

</html>
</body>
```

The above code is working and downloading an Excel file with correct data as soon as I run the app. I want it to wait until the user clicks the `Excel` button and then download the spreadsheet. How could I achieve this? I'm new to both Django and HTML.

Comment: What are do your urls.py files look like? Make sure you have something like `path('Export/', views.write_to_excel, name='write_to_excel'),` and `path('Export/', include('myapp.urls')),` then you will need to add a form action: `action="/Export/"`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your urls.py files its hard to direct you exactly but it should look something like this:

## Views.py

```
def exportFile():

    df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['abc', 'def'], 'col2': ['ghi', 'jkl']})

    resp = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=myFile.csv'

    df.to_csv(path_or_buf=resp, sep=',', index=False)
    return resp
```

## myApp\urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
               path('myApp/export/', include('app.urls')),
              ]
```

## app\urls.py

```
urlpatters = [
              path('myApp/export/', views.exportFile, name='exportFile'),
             ]
```

## myApp.html

```
<form name="exportFile" action="/myApp/export/" method="get">
<input type="submit" id="exportFile" name="exportFile" value="Export">
</form>
```